# Are there restrictions on GAE Datanucleus * query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus, gae-eclipse-plugin

Does anyone know if there are any restrictions to using `*` queries in datanucleus JPA for the google app-engine (GAE) datastore? My query is

```
SELECT * FROM Pen p WHERE p.owner = :owner order by p.price desc
```

I need to assemble a list of Pen entities/objects and associated data to send to client. I can't do key only because I need the actual entities. But I often here of the slowness of `*` queries in relational databases.

I already have the table/entity indexed on `owner` and `price`

Answer (score 0):

You mean apart from the fact that `"SELECT *"` is illegal in JPQL? If you put `"SELECT p FROM ..."` then fine. [Google's Java docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2) defines what their datastore supports, i.e no joins. And this is Google's datastore and their plugin doing the querying NOT 'DataNucleus'